# Find duplicate records (phone ) from two table mysql select query

Tags: mysql

I am running below query to get duplicate records from existing table. Below is the process i am doing

1. Uploading CSV
2. Load data in to temp table
3. writing query to check if duplicate records with same phone # already exist in table by joining temporary table and current table.

My query is working fine upto 100,000 records in current table but on live system data in current table is more that 10,000,000 so query output is timed out .

my query is

```
select 
tempTbl.id + 1 as SrNo, 
`tempTbl`.`phone` as `phone`, 
(  CASE WHEN count(panelists.id) > 1 THEN 
        CONCAT( CONCAT('Phone Already Exist with Panelist ID ', panelists.id 
,' and Duplidate counts is ',count('panelists.id'))
    ELSE    
         CONCAT('Phone Already Exist with Panelist ID ',' ',panelists.id)
    END
 ) AS reason from `panelists` as `panelists` 
inner join `temp` as `tempTbl` on `panelists`.`phone` = `tempTbl`.`phone` 
where `panelists`.`panel_id` = ? group by `tempTbl`.`phone` 
having tempTbl.phone != ''
```

I would be thankful if any help suggestion to optimize my query . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you have a query writing a query? That string doesn't do anything unless you execute it.

Comment: I am executing this query in my code but output is timed - out

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked and tried to  change and increase  default value in MySQL configuration file (option connect_timeout in mysqld section) -

```
[mysqld] connect_timeout=100
```

Please see and compare the Configuration parameter in both the databases servers.If query is getting executed successfully on one server we can check the configuration params of the both.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. my response is 504 Gateway Time-out nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu) . will it work if i change mysql configuration file. i am running this query from php .  is there any chance to optimize the query ?